# What are the sealing techniques used to contain the Tailed Beasts?

Tags: naruto

When Naruto was asked by Killer Bee: "What is the sealing technique use to contain the Nine-Tails?", Naruto said that it is the "Four Element Seal". In return, Killer Bee said that the sealing technique used to contain the Eight-Tails is the "Iron Fist Seal". Now I want to know what are the other sealing techniques to contain the other Tailed Beast.

So far we have the following:

```
Nine-Tails:  Four Element
Eight-Tails: Iron Fist
```

Comment: P.S.: I added a bounty for an answer that makes extended research about this question.

Comment: Adding a bounty doesn't really matter, because there is nothing mentioned in the manga. So unless someone makes them up, that's the two you'll have for some time.

Comment: Even though *there is nothing mentioned in the manga*, I want answers like from @Happy that done extensive research on the question. However, you can still answer the question if the "unreleased episodes" mention anything about these sealing techniques.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer is based upon events up to Chapter 644.

Following techniques have been used for sealing Tailed Beasts.

- **Hakke no Fūin Shiki (Eight Trigrams Sealing Style)** used by Namikaze Minato to seal yang-Kurama (Kyuubi) into infant Naruto (and yin-Kurama into himself).
- **Tekkō Fūin (Iron Armour Seal)** used to seal Gyūki (Hachibi) into Bee (and Fukai, the previous Hachibi jinchuriki).
- **Fūinjutsu: Genryū Kyūfūjin (Sealing Technique: Phantom Dragons Nine Consuming Seals)** used by Akatsuki members to (extract and) seal their captured bijū into the Gedō Mazō.
- ***Unnamed Fūinjutsu*** used by Chiyo to attach Shukaku (Ichibi) to Gaara's unborn body. The same technique was presumably used to attach Shukaku to the previous two jinchuriki.
- **Ten-tails sealing technique** used by Uchiha Obito to seal the Juubi into himself.
- ***Undisclosed Fūinjutsu*** used by Uchiha Obito to reseal various bijū into their resurrected former jinchuriki.
- **Kohaku no Jōhei bijū fūin (Amber Purifying Pot Tailed-beast sealing)** used by the Third Raikage to seal Hachibi into the Kohaku no Jōhei.

Other jinchurikis probably got their bijūs through one of the above techniques, or other as yet undisclosed techniques.

There is not much evidence, direct or circumstantial, to suggest any kind of "compatibility requirement" between a bijū and its sealing technique, or in other words, it sounds plausible that a bijū could be sealed using more than one technique, and the same sealing technique could be used to seal various bijū (as seen in the above examples).

Comment: Very good answer! Glad to see you're still alive :)

Comment: Indeed a good answer, but still my curiosity don't satisfy. Nevertheless, you deserve to have the bounty than the other answer since you clearly done extensive research. But before I award the bounty, can you give reference to your answer specially the sealing technique used by the Third Raikage to seal Hachibi into the Kohaku no Jōhei.

PS: I never knew about **Amber Purifying Pot Tailed-beast sealing** so thanks for that.

Comment: Sure, I will add the references shortly. By the way, I have added about as much information as is currently available (I think). To satisfy your curiosity further, you will have to contact Kishimoto-sama. :)

Comment: Also, I don't know if it is possible to award the bounty before the time runs out, but I recommend waiting till the time is up, as you might get an even better answer!

Comment: If i am not wrong Minato used two kind of sealings.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific sealing technique for each tailed beast. In the battle with killer B, B stated that the Iron Fist seal is of a lower quality that the Four Element seal. B was simply questioning the quality of Naruto's seal. B also stated that Naruto's seal was a lot more durable when compared to the Iron Fist seal.

B's seal is of a lower quality and is therefor easier to break. In the anime it appeared that the Five Element Unseal was strong enough to break B's seal. Naruto's seal is of a higher quality so it is harder to break but it is also much harder to create.

It does not really matter which seal you use as long as it is strong enough to seal the Tailed  Beast.

Comment: but that wasn't his question. He wants to know (as do I) if the sealing techniques for the other tailed beasts and jinchuriki have been mentioned in the manga. Would be an interresting study.. :)